# Duplicate Row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the total count and the distinct count in a table where no single column has a unique record

Can anybody please help me to write a query tailored to performance.

Comment: I highly recommend that you elaborate on your question. Give some examples of what your table looks like, also what query have you tried so far? etc

Comment: show me your effort and table records

Comment: Give some information or data so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` and `GROUP BY` all columns, and filter by `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`:

```sql
SELECT   ColA
        ,ColB
        ,ColC
        ,COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Rows
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ColA
        ,ColB
        ,ColC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(1)` for total count and `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` for distinct count.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS [TotalCount],
       COUNT(DISTINCT ColA) AS [ColACount]
FROM [YourTable]
```

Comment: sir if i use COUNT(DISTINCT ColA)  it will count distinct value from that column only if i am mistaking correct me might i am weak in fundamental

Comment: @SachinJawalkar, Yes, you are right.. if you want distinct count of some other column add another count(distinct) with that column name in the select.